# código de salida 3221225477: el programa se rompe

Tags: c++, punteros, vectores, sfml

creé un juego como proyecto final de una materia y está bastante avanzado. Es una imitación del Dinochrome: un gatito que tiene que esquivar obstáculos y le agregué un premio que le suma puntos cuando los junta.
Para controlar el flujo de ambas cosas hice un vector dinámico de su clase base, ObjetosSinTextura. El problema es que el programa se rompe si al principio de la partida se genera un  objeto de la clase Obstáculo y el gatito colisiona con él. Si colisiona con un objeto de la clase Prmeio no se rompe.
Sé el problema está relacionado con el vector dinámico, pero no se exactamente en donde.
Les dejo el fragmento de código del proyecto donde se genera el problema:

```
bool estaafuera(ObjetoSinTex *obj){ // si la coordenada x es menor a la del final de la pantalla retorna true.
    return obj->posicion().x==-10;
}

void Match::Update ( Game &gamee ) {
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Escape)){ // para volver a Menu
        gamee.SetScene(new Menu());
    }
    
    /// updates
    player.Update();
    
    for(int i = 0; i<objetos.size(); i++) {
        objetos[i]->Update();
        if( player.colisionaCon(objetos[i]) && objetos[i]->esPremio()){ // colision player-obstaculos
            puntaje += 10;
            delete objetos[i];
            objetos.erase(objetos.begin() + i); // si agarra un premio -el clip- le suma 10 ptos
            
        }else if(player.colisionaCon(objetos[i]) && !objetos[i]->esPremio() ){
            gamee.SetScene(new GameOver(puntaje)); // si no, pierde
        }
    }

    Time time_objetos = tiempoenemigos.getElapsedTime();
    float secsPassed  = time_objetos.asSeconds();
    
    if(secsPassed >= distan) { // condicional para q los objetos se generen a cierta distancia
        
        ObjetoSinTex *aux_obj ;
        
        int elige = rand() % 2;  // para crear premio u obstaculo
        
        if(elige == 1){ // premio
            premio_texture = new sf::Texture;
            premio_texture->loadFromFile("clip.png");
            aux_obj = new Premio(premio_texture,speed);
            aux_obj->AsignarPos(min_y,max_y);
            objetos.push_back(aux_obj);
            
        } else { // obstaculo
            string file_elegido = elegirText(); // para variar la textura de enemigo
            enemy_texture = new sf::Texture;
            enemy_texture->loadFromFile(file_elegido);
            aux_obj = new Obstaculo(enemy_texture,speed);
            aux_obj->AsignarPos(min_y,max_y);
            objetos.push_back(aux_obj);
        }
        
        speed = speed-0.2; // la velocidad aumenta gradualmente.
        
        int valordistan = rand()%3;
        if(valordistan == 1){ 
            distan=distan-0.02; // se genera mas cerca
        } else {
            if(valordistan == 2){
                distan = distan + 0.10; // se genera mas lejos
            } else {
                distan = distan-0.15; // se genera mucho mas cerca
            }
        }
        tiempoenemigos.restart();
    }
    
    auto it = remove_if(objetos.begin(),objetos.end(),estaafuera);
    objetos.erase(it,objetos.end());
    scoreToStr = to_string(puntaje);
}

Match::~Match(){
    cout <<"libera la memoria de la partida" << endl;
    for (auto &o :objetos)
    {
        delete o;
    } 
    delete premio_texture;
    delete enemy_texture;
}
```

Comment: Que libreria grafica estas usando para dicho proyecto?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Objetos sin procesar**

```
for(int i = 0; i<objetos.size(); i++) { // <<--- 2
    objetos[i]->Update();
    if( player.colisionaCon(objetos[i]) && objetos[i]->esPremio()){ // colision player-obstaculos
        puntaje += 10;
        delete objetos[i];                  
        objetos.erase(objetos.begin() + i); // <<--- 1
        
    }else if(player.colisionaCon(objetos[i]) && !objetos[i]->esPremio() ){
        gamee.SetScene(new GameOver(puntaje)); // si no, pierde
    }
}
```

1. Eliminas un objeto del array
2. Te saltas un objeto de la lista

Sí, así es. Cuando eliminas el objeto de la posición `i` desplazas todos los demás una posición hacia adelante, así el objeto que estaba en `i+1` pasa es tar en `i`, pero como en el bucle incrementas incondicionalmente el valor de `i`, puesss mala suerte para ese objeto

Si sigues usando índices puedes decrementar `i`:

```
delete objetos[i];
objetos.erase(objetos.begin() + i);
i--;
```

O bien puedes recorrer el array a la inversa. De esta forma al borrar un objeto se desplazarán objetos que ya han sido procesados por el array

```
for( int i=objetos.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
```

También puedes pasar a usar iteradores. Más limpio en estos casos:

```
for( auto it = objetos.begin(); it != objetos.end(); /* No hacemos nada en este caso */)
{
    auto* objeto = *it;
    objeto->Update();

    if( player.colisionaCon(objeto) && objeto->esPremio()){
        puntaje += 10;
        delete objeto;
        it = objetos.erase(it);
    } else if (player.colisionaCon(objeto) && !objeto->esPremio() ){
        gamee.SetScene(new GameOver(puntaje));
        // Si es GameOver, quizás se debería abandonar el bucle
    } else {
        ++it 
    }
}
```

**No reutilizas texturas**

Para cada objeto `premio` creas una textura, cuando todos los premios comparten la misma textura:

```
        premio_texture = new sf::Texture;
        premio_texture->loadFromFile("clip.png");
        aux_obj = new Premio(premio_texture,speed);
        aux_obj->AsignarPos(min_y,max_y);
        objetos.push_back(aux_obj);
```

La tarjeta gráfica tiene un límite de texturas ... y no has puesto cómo funcionan los destructores de los objetos `Premio` y `Obstaculo`. Si no borras las texturas correctamente corres el riesgo de *llenar* la tarjeta gráfica con texturas y entonces dejará de aceptar texturas nuevas. Con los obstáculos te pasa exactamente lo mismo (aunque sean diferentes, llegará un momento en el que se repitan).

Quizás sea buena idea precargar las texturas (una única vez cada una) y símplemente le vas a asignando a cada objeto la textura que le corresponda. Este mecanismo, aparte de ser más óptimo, simplifica la gestión de las texturas.

**No destruyes objetos**

Esta es una buena forma de llenar la memoria de basura: No destruir los objetos cuando ya no los necesitas:

```
auto it = remove_if(objetos.begin(),objetos.end(),estaafuera);
objetos.erase(it,objetos.end());
```

Lo que haces en estas dos líneas es, simplemente, sacar del array los objetos que ya no son visibles ... pero no los destruyes, por lo que siguen ocupando memoria (y ya hilando con el tema anterior, su propia copia de la textura).

El parche en este caso es trivial:

```
auto it = remove_if(objetos.begin(),objetos.end(),estaafuera);

// Forma 1
for( auto it2 = it; it2!=objetos.end(); ++it2)
    delete *it2;

// Forma 2 - reemplaza TIPO_BASE por el tipo usado al declarar la lista objetos -> std::vector<TIPO_BASE>
std::for_each(it, objetos.end(), std::default_delete<TIPO_BASE>());


objetos.erase(it,objetos.end());
```

**Posible borrado doble de texturas**

```
Match::~Match(){
    cout <<"libera la memoria de la partida" << endl;
    for (auto &o :objetos)
    {
        delete o;          // <<--- 3
    } 
    delete premio_texture; // <<--- 1
    delete enemy_texture;  // <<--- 2
}
```

Si resulta que has programado correctamente el destructor de `Premio` y `Obstaculo`, entonces en (3) estarás liberando **todas las texturas** ... sin embargo luego llegan las líneas (1) y (2) y tratas de liberar otra vez las dos últimas texturas ... esto normalmente se conoce como **double delete** y no es un efecto divertido.

Los punteros `premio_texture` y `enemy_texture` deberían ser locales en la función `Match::Update` ya que o bien las texturas las tienes precargadas o bien dependen de cada objeto:

- Si las tienes precargadas, se deberán borrar **todas** al acabar el juego, no solo las dos últimas
- Si cada objeto tiene su propia textura, entonces es responsabilidad de **cada objeto** destruir la textura asociada.

El código podría quedar así:

```
    if(elige == 1){ // premio
        pf::Texture* texture = new sf::Texture; // Variable local
        texture ->loadFromFile("clip.png");
        aux_obj = new Premio(texture ,speed);
        aux_obj->AsignarPos(min_y,max_y);
        objetos.push_back(aux_obj);
        
    } else { // obstaculo
        string file_elegido = elegirText(); // para variar la textura de enemigo
        pf::Texture* texture = new sf::Texture; // Variable local
        texture ->loadFromFile(file_elegido);
        aux_obj = new Obstaculo(texture ,speed);
        aux_obj->AsignarPos(min_y,max_y);
        objetos.push_back(aux_obj);
    }
```

Y esto es todo lo que puedo rascar a partir del código que has publicado. Espero que te esto te guíe para resolver otros problemas que tengas en el programa